# How do I pass an element ID into my jQuery function

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I'm using Ben Nadel's iFrame Upload function for an editing tool on a site I'm working on. I'm learning jQuery. The function works beautifully. It's part of a reuseable modal window and everything works. But, I want to dynamically tell the function where the call came from so it loads the proper form into the modal window. How would I pass that into the function. Right now it's hard coded to receive for #uploadform. Essentially, I want to re-use the function and drop in the varialbles like the action, preview and form ID etc...

```
$(function(){
                var jForm = $( "#uploadform" );
                jForm.submit(
                    function( objEvent ){
                    var jThis = $( this );
                    var strName = ("uploader" + (new Date()).getTime());
                    var jFrame = $( "<iframe name=\"" + strName + "\" src=\"about:blank\" />" );
                    jFrame.css( "display", "none" );
                    jFrame.load(
                        function( objEvent ){
                            var objUploadBody = window.frames[ strName ].document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[ 0 ];
                            var jBody = $( objUploadBody );
                            var objData = eval( "(" + jBody.html() + ")" )
                            var thumb = ('thumbnails/' + eval(jBody.html()));
                            $("#header").css("background", "url(" + thumb + ") no-repeat center");
                            $("#preview").attr("src", thumb);
                    setTimeout(
                        function(){
                            jFrame.remove();
                            },100);
                });
            $( "body:first" ).append( jFrame );
            jThis
                .attr( "action", "upload_act_single.cfm" )
                .attr( "method", "post" )
                .attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" )
                .attr( "encoding", "multipart/form-data" )
                .attr( "target", strName );
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going to suggest something similar except create a separate function for the occasion:

```
function formSubmit(formId) {
   var jForm = $("#"+formId);
   //remainder of your code
}
```

Next, for each form create your onSubmit connection either directly when declaring the html form:

```
<form id="myForm" class="pageForms" onsubmit="function(formSubmit(this.id))> ...
```

Or programatically:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
   formSubmit("#myForm");
});
```

[OR]

```
$(".pageForms").submit(function() { //to apply to all forms within the document
    formSubmit("#"+this.id);         //with that class
});
```

OR for all forms in the document (but not sure if it will work)

```
$("form").submit(function() { 
   formSubmit("#"+this.id);
});
```

Remember to perform the attachment in the onLoad function [$(function(){ ... })] or otherwise javascript errors could occur :S

Comment: So, essentially my upload is wrapped in the formSubmit function, correct? If that is the case, I suspect that would also allow me to define my other vars like where the for submits and some other data I would like to include in the submit. Would this also allow me to auto-submit if I did an onChange in my file input field as opposed to onSubmit?

Comment: Exactly, you can define the method and action within the standard HTML form element and call them with basic javascript via this.action/this.method. Therefore, only need for one jQuery function! Yes you could use an onChange trigger instead and just use the $("formElement.id").val() in the data to be submitted. 

You should look at the dojo toolkit, specifically dojo.xhrGet / dojo.xhrPost (or dojo.io.iframe.send for multi-part form data) methods ;)

Answer (score 0):

try `$(this).attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFunction = function(formid) {
  var jForm = $( formid );
  // ....
}

$(function() {
  myFunction("#uploadform");
});
$(function() {
  myFunction("#uploadform2");
});
```